# mysql date time indexes not applying for some specific date ranges

Tags: mysql, indexing, date-range

I have a table with this schema -

```
CREATE TABLE `ox_data_summary_device_hourly` (
  `data_summary_device_hourly_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  ...
   
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`data_summary_device_hourly_id`),
  KEY `ox_data_summary_device_daily_date_time` (`date_time`),
  KEY `ox_data_summary_device_daily_ad_country_date_time` (`ad_id`,`date_time`),
  KEY `ox_data_summary_device_daily_zone_id_date_time` (`zone_id`,`date_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3478837682 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

So, the following indexes are set on a table -

```
 KEY `ox_data_summary_device_daily_date_time` (`date_time`),
 KEY `ox_data_summary_device_daily_ad_country_date_time` (`ad_id`,`date_time`),
 KEY `ox_data_summary_device_daily_zone_id_date_time` (`zone_id`,`date_time`)
```

I have this explain query on this table with filter on `date_time` -

```
explain SELECT *

FROM ox_data_summary_device_hourly data_hourly 

WHERE 
data_hourly.date_time >= '2012-09-01 00:00:00' AND data_hourly.date_time < '2012-09-15 13:00:00' 

GROUP BY data_hourly.type ORDER BY data_hourly.type DESC
```

Here is the output showing that the `ox_data_summary_device_daily_date_time` index is not applying -

[image]

However, if I change the date filter in the above mentioned query to the following -

`data_hourly.date_time >= '2012-09-01 00:00:00' AND data_hourly.date_time < '2012-09-14 13:00:00'`

i.e. if I query for 1st Sep to 14 sep instead of 1st to 15 sep, the `ox_data_summary_device_daily_date_time` index applies. I further checked that if the end date of the range is anything after `15 sep`, the index does not apply.

I am puzzled. I checked that there is data in the table for date range >= 15th Sep.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the index is not being used, but you might solve this by adding the `FORCE INDEX` option:

```
SELECT *
FROM ox_data_summary_device_hourly data_hourly 
FORCE INDEX (ox_data_summary_device_daily_date_time)
WHERE 
data_hourly.date_time >= '2012-09-01 00:00:00' AND 
data_hourly.date_time < '2012-09-15 13:00:00' 
GROUP BY data_hourly.type ORDER BY data_hourly.type DESC
```

Also, you may find using the `BETWEEN` operator easier to read, and it may even perform slightly better:

```
SELECT *
FROM ox_data_summary_device_hourly data_hourly 
FORCE INDEX (ox_data_summary_device_daily_date_time)
WHERE 
data_hourly.date_time BETWEEN 
    '2012-09-01 00:00:00' AND 
    '2012-09-15 13:00:00' - INTERVAL 1 SECOND
GROUP BY data_hourly.type ORDER BY data_hourly.type DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the optimizer to me - it thinks there are too many rows being examined by the query to make the index useful.  That explains why it's OK for a smaller range, too.

I think you can either query for smaller date ranges or use a DATE instead of a DATETIME.

Running ANALYZE or OPTIMIZE might help, too.  Here's a decent [overview article](http://www.pythian.com/news/1114/mysql-back-to-basics-analyze-check-optimize-and-repair/)

Good luck.